# DatePickerDialog showing only the current date and onwards (Xamarin Android C#)

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

How to set the current date on DatePickerDialog when it opens? I have searched for several sources but none of them are in Xamarin Android (mostly xamarin.forms, android studio java). I am trying to figure out the syntaxes on xamarin.forms but it is hard to compare it to xamarin android.

I am coding from a fragment

```
private int year, month, day;

Button eventpickdateButton;
TextInputLayout eventdatesetText;

public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.newevent, container, false);
            this.Dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

            eventpickdateButton = (Button)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.eventpickdateButton);
            eventdatesetText = (TextInputLayout)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.eventdatesetText);

            eventpickdateButton.Click += EventpickdateButton_Click;

            return view;
        }

        private void EventpickdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this.Activity, this, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.Show();
        }
      
        public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            this.year = year;
            this.month = month + 1;
            this.day = dayOfMonth;
            eventdatesetText.EditText.Text = month + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year;
        }
```

and for some reason, my month does not add + 1 when picking a date. Whenever I pick January as a month, it shows "0/dd/yyyy" even though I added 1 to its value. Why is that? Thank you for future answers. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see you define eventdatesetText in the provided code, you can try to change your code to:

```
eventdatesetText.EditText.Text = this.month + "/" + this.day+ "/" + this.year;
```

or

```
eventdatesetText.EditText.Text = month+1 + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year;
```

In Xamarin.Android's official documentation about the use of DatePickerDialog, you can refer to the following documentation for more details: [Android Date Picker | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/pickers/date-picker#extending-dialogfragment)

Comment: I editted my code but you answered my question! thank you! I used `eventdatesetText.EditText.Text = this.month + "/" + this.day+ "/" + this.year;` and it finally read the +1 on the month! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sir @Donzhi, do you have any idea or some syntax to whenever I open the datepickerdialog, it will only display the current date onwards? Thank you for the reply if ever. I appreciate it.